# Github Project Login Failure

Tags: mysql, github

I was looking to set up an opensource inventory management project available on github for development purpose. I did exactly as stated  in the project documentation and when I uploaded it to the live server and entered the user name and password provided in documentation i.e admin/admin the system gives an error that the USERNAME does not exist. I am new to php and mysql. I would really appreciate if someone can go through the documentation and share a fix.

I have little experience with database so could find a possible solution.

Please refer to the link below:
https://github.com/stemword/php-inventory-management-system

Comment: Have you tried login into the database and looking checking the `users` table to confirm if the user exists?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was just testing the deployment and what i did is downloaded the zip and uploaded it to live server. I have not set up the database. Request you to kindly go through the documentation and share what table do i need to create.

Comment: Can i add it from the cpanel or please share the sql format that i can use.

Comment: I've read the documentation on that and it assumes that the user understands PHP and MySQL, if you're not familiar with either of those, I'd recommend you to read up on them to get a basic understanding of it https://www.w3schools.com/ has pretty good tutorials. As per CPannel question, it depends on the provider you went with, they all varies

Comment: You must set up the database before you attempt to deploy this app. The author of this package provided almost no information on how to do that, just `admin` / `admin`.

Comment: Thanks, could you please share a format to fix the issue. I can add it using Cpanel > phpmyadmin. I only require to add username and password fields.

Comment: Arrrrgh! w3schools?  Friends don't let friends.  Their tutorials are OK until you get stuck because they made a mistake.

Comment: As written, this app is unsuitable for use on a shared server. Why? it uses `localhost` / `root` / `root` as [host / username / password](https://github.com/stemword/php-inventory-management-system/blob/master/php_action/db_connect.php) for logging in to the MySQL database.

Comment: I was thinking if I could use something like#

+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| Username   | Name       | Password +------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|  | admin       | admin         | admin      
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+